# Log normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Given a random variable $X$ with log normal distribution, can we find the probability of $X$ being greater than a positive constant $a$, i.e can we determine the integral
$$
\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{xs\sqrt{2\pi}}  e^{-(\ln(x)-s)^2/(2s^2)} dx 
$$
from a to infinity?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is equivalent to that of finding $Pr[Z\ge s^{-1}\log a] = \Phi(s^{-1}\log a)$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. There is no closed form expression for this value. Any statistical package will give you a numeric approximation. Also, there are analytic bounds of arbitrary sharpness available ([ref](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2063))

Comment: Can you please name such a package? I actually want to find the value of a for which the integral is maximized.

Comment: R-project is free and excellent.

Comment: if I understood you correctly, you want to maximize $a\mapsto Pr[X\ge a]$ where $X$ has log-normal distribution?

Comment: Yes, the actual problem I am working on is to find the value of a for which Pr(X>=a) is maximized.

Comment: $Pr[X\ge a]$ is bounded above by $1$ and is monotone decreasing in $a$ on $(0,\infty)$. That is, there is no maximum.

Comment: Okay, thanks! But can you please prove your statement?

Comment: Well, it's more of an axiom than a statement. The only fact we need to agree on, is that $Pr[Z<a]$ is strictly positive for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ for $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes I completely missed that. Thanks!